# Inheritence & Scope Resolution in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand why I need the scope resolution operator to access constants in an inherited module but not methods. Assuming:

```
module Foo
  SOMETHING = {:one => 1, :two => 2}
  def showit
    p SOMETHING
  end
end
```

and

```
class Bar
  include Foo
  def initialize 
    # why doesn't method name need scope resolution but const does?
    showit
    p Foo::SOMETHING
  end
```

Also related, can you access instance or local variables declared in Foo from Bar? I tried something like this:

```
module Foo
  @myar = "some string"
  myvar2 = "some other string"
  def showit
    p @myvar
    p myvar2
  end
end
```

and calling showit from within the Bar class...printing @myvar resulted in nil and myvar2 was undefined. I would expect both strings to print...what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't have to scope the constant.

This should run just fine.

```
class Bar
  include Foo
  def initialize 
    showit
    p SOMETHING # instead of Foo::SOMETHING
  end
end

Bar.new
```